# Variables initialized and displayed in ODS although if-statement is FALSE

Tags: sas

I have implemented an `IF-statement` in a `SAS` program which basically checks the validity of a year comparison. If the `IF-statement` is `TRUE`some further variables are initialized and computed, if `IF-statement` is `FALSE` nothing happens.

However, I just realized that no matter if the `IF-statement` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` the additional variables will be initialized (though as `MISSING` in the `FALSE` case) and displayed in the `ODS`. Why is that? Is there a direct way to solve this? I could of course use a conditional `drop-statement` but this seems tedious to always add this.

```
data test; 

value = 1;
if value > 2019 then a = 1;

/*
if value < 2019 then 
    do; 
        drop a;
    end;
*/

run;
```

**EDIT:** Again I just realized that the `drop-statement` will also always drop no matter if `TRUE/FALSE`.

**Solution** *but no idea why it works*:

```
data test; 

%let value = 1;
%if &value. > 2019 %then %do; a = 1; %end;

run;
```

While digging around I found [this sas-community post](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/When-to-use-IF-and-IF-in-Macros/td-p/104978). My problem seems to basically stem from the difference of `%IF vs IF`. Applying the `MACRO %IF` it works. The post seems to be a bit out date, as opposed to the post one can *now* use `MACRO %IF` outside of a `MACRO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the difference between compiling and running a datastep. When a datastep is compiled (before it's actually run), SAS figures out what variables it's going to need. Since the column `a` is on the left-hand side of an equation, it gets added to the dataset. Remember, at this point, SAS has no idea what data you're going to be putting into it; you might need that `a` column, you might not. That's why you can't conditionally add/remove columns during run-time; the columns need to be known at compilation.

In the second case, as Tom pointed out, the macro expressions are being evaluated *before* the datastep is compiled. From SAS' point of view, your code:

```
data test; 

%let value = 1;
%if &value. > 2019 %then %do; a = 1; %end;

run;
```

Just evaluates to this:

```
data test; 

run;
```

On the other hand, this code:

```
data test; 

%let value = 2020;
%if &value. > 2019 %then %do; a = 1; %end;

run;
```

Would evaluate to this:

```
data test; 

a = 1;

run;
```

Comment: Thx! So basically it's not possible to filter with `data step variables` in a `data step` without initializing them?

Comment: Yup, you aren't able to conditionally add or remove variables during a datastep itself, since the columns need to be known before the datastep is actually executed. However, if you wanted to, you could do this in two datasteps, by running through the data once, creating a macro variable with whatever columns you want to drop/keep, then calling it in a second datastep. Macro variables just evaluate to text, so you can use them in place of whatever SAS code you want.

Answer (score 1):

MACRO code and SAS code are two different systems. The macro processor checks the code first and interprets any macro code (looking for % and & triggers). The resulting text then continues on and is evaluated as SAS code.

So in your second case the macro processor generates different SAS code based on the value of the macro variable.

Also note that your cases are testing different things.  In the macro code you are testing the value of a macro variable. In the data step code you are testing the value of dataset variable (for a particular observation).

Comment: Thx again! Somehow I wasn't aware of the MACRO preprocessing...it seems like adding MACRO variables to a data step is some kind of new feature (at least it seems so following the community post). Before this, you were just wrapping a MACRO around the data step?

Comment: You can use macro code (or just simple macro variable expansion) any where you want.  You just need to understand the timing of when the macro expressions are evaluated and when the resulting SAS code runs.